# Using googlecl with a non-Gmail address

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to build a small toolbox of scripts such that I can automate some tasks involving Google contacts, calendar and so on.  Most of the work is already done by means of the `googlecl` project, which looks very promising.

As far as I understand the process, `googlecl` needs to request an authentication ticket from Google by means of OAuth.  Admittedly, I have only a sketchy notion of what is going on there, but that’s something that Wikipedia will help me solve.

**Here’s the catch:**  My Google account uses a non-Gmail address (let it be `vucar@example.invalid` for the sake of this discussion).  The account was created back in the old days when Google didn’t force GMail down people’s throats who have no use for it.  `googlecl` will direct me to `https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken?oauth_token=…&hd=example.invalid` to complete the OAuth handshake.  Google will then tell me that ‘the domain name has not been signed up for Google Apps’.  Which is correct.

If I *don’t* supply my user ID to `googlecl`, then the URL reads `…&hd=default`.  Google will accept the OAuth request, granting whichever permissions needed to my locally running `googlecl`, but then `googlecl` will complain that the token was issued to a different user ID than for the user ID that was requested.  Which of course is also correct.

I’ve read through https://support.google.com/a/answer/33419, which in turn redirects me to http://www.google.com/a in order to ‘to sign up your domain for Google Apps’.  Apparently, if my Google account uses a domain different from @gmail.com, then I am a business user and need to *purchase* Google Apps for my domain—to get, amonst a truckload of other stuff, my domain connected to GMail, the polar opposite of what I wanted to have by having that ‘foreign’ domain in the first place.

I have to admit that I am stymied.  I understand what OAuth in this case is used for, but I fail to grasp the byzantine reasoning at Google’s.  I do not believe that I want Google Apps for my domain, and I *especially* do not want to hand over my emails or anything else to Google.  I merely want to access and modify my data at Google’s, with my user ID happening not to end in @gmail.com.

Is it strictly required that I purchase *Google Apps for Work* for such a configuration?  The contacts, calendars and so forth is already at Google’s, and used from both Google’s web site and Android clients.  The only thing new to the mix is API access.